# Parse error: syntax error. Unexpected '{' - I have no idea what's wrong

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/u696221601/public_html/wp-content/themes/oblivion/themeOptions/functions.php on line 3
```

on this line:

```
<?php
phpif ( !function_exists( 'optionsframework_init' ) )
{
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/     /* Options Framework Theme/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/       /* Set the file path based on whether the Options Framework Theme is a parent theme or child theme */

    if ( get_stylesheet_directory() == get_template_directory() )
    {
```

Answer (score 5):

Try changing this

```
phpif ( !function_exists( 'optionsframework_init' ) )
{
```

to

```
if ( !function_exists( 'optionsframework_init' ) )
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ( !function_exists( 'optionsframework_init' ) )
{

   if ( get_stylesheet_directory() == get_template_directory() )
   {
      //do somting    
   }
}
```